# Inner-product of matrices and semidefiniteness

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, trace, symmetric-matrices, positive-semidefinite

> Show that $$\langle\ \phi,X^TX+Y^TY - (Y^TX)^T - Y^TX \rangle\ \geq 0$$ where $\phi$ is a symmetric positive semidefinite matrix and $X, Y \in R^{m \times n}$.

Is my reasoning correct?

$$\langle\ \phi,X^TX+Y^TY - (Y^TX)^T - Y^TX \rangle\ =\operatorname{tr}(\phi X^T (X-Y) ) + \operatorname{tr}(\phi Y^T (Y-X) ) =\\ =\operatorname{tr}( \phi (X-Y)^T(X-Y))\geq 0$$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's correct provided that the inner product is defined by $\langle A,B\rangle=\operatorname{tr}(AB^T)$ (or equivalently, by $\langle A,B\rangle=\operatorname{tr}(A^TB)$), but the proof is more complete if you explain why the last inequality holds: by the tracial property, $\operatorname{tr}(\phi(X-Y)^T(X-Y))=\operatorname{tr}((X-Y)\phi(X-Y)^T)$ and the latter trace is $\ge0$ because $(X-Y)\phi(X-Y)^T$ is positive semidefinite.

Comment: Thanks for your response. Isn't $A^TA$ psd?

Comment: @Teodorism It's in the form of $BA^TA$ ($B=\phi$, $A=X-Y$), not simply $A^TA$.

Comment: What I meant to say is a matrix $B$ is psd (e.g., $B:=A^TA$) iff $\operatorname{tr}(\phi B)\geq 0,\ \forall \phi$ psd.

Comment: @Teodorism Yes, you may state that as well (but strictly speaking, it's that a **real symmetric** matrix $B$ is PSD iff the trace of $\phi B$ is nonnegative for all PSD $\phi$; if $B$ is skew-symmetric, we have $tr(\phi B)=0$ as well, but $B$ isn't PSD).